A question on the tangent space of a sphere
It is universally acknowledged* that the tangent space of a sphere
$S^{d-1} = \{ \mathbf{x} | \mathbf{x^\top x} = 1, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d \}$
at a point $\mathbf{x}_0$ is
$T_{\mathbf{x}_0} S^{d-1} = \{ \mathbf{v} | \mathbf{x}_0^\top \mathbf{v}=0, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^d \}$.
But the points that fulfill $\mathbf{x}_0^\top \mathbf{v}=0$ actually form a line/plane that goes through the origin instead of $\mathbf{x}_0$.
Isn't it a better idea to rewrite $T_{\mathbf{x}_0} S^{d-1}$ as $\{ \mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{v} | \mathbf{x}_0^\top \mathbf{v}=0, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^d \}$?
* I have seen it in An introduction to optimization on smooth manifolds and somewhere else.

It's better described as a space of directions one can go from $\mathbf{x}_0$. Anyway, it's supposed to be a vector space, so you do in fact want it to go through the origin.

Shout-out to Jane Austen.

We should not say that the tangent space "is" that vector space, but it is isomorphic to it.  Strictly speaking, depending on your definition, a tangent vector to a manifold is an equivalence class of curves through the point that have the same velocity in some coordinate system. Your idea about $\bf{x}_0+\bf{v}$
fits somewhat with that because
$t\to \bf{x}_0+t\bf{v}$
is such a curve.
